# Redirect in an url link after commenting in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, function

I  have  this code but it is not working.

```
add_action('comment_post_redirect', 'your_redirect_function');

// A function that redirects your users after they have commented.
function your_redirect_function ($location, $comment) {
    // Here all you need to do is return the url of your target page.
    $page = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';
    return $page;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The difference is mostly technical, but this should be done using `add_filter`, not `add_action`. Try this, and include the priority and number of parameters: `add_filter( 'comment_post_redirect', 'your_redirect_function', 10, 2 );`